# Ubuntu return deinstalled package

Tags: ubuntu

```
root@randevu:~# dpkg --get-selections | grep postfix
postfix     deinstall
```

Is it possible to return back deinstalled package? I'm wondering how could postfix be deinstalled. I haven't done it manually. Can apt-get or aptitude do it itself?

```
/etc/init.d/postfix start
/etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

returns nothing, just a silence.

Configs are in place inside /etc/postfix/.

```
root@randevu:~# dpkg -L postfix
/etc
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/postfix
/etc/ppp
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d
/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/postfix
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d
/etc/ppp/ip-down.d/postfix
/etc/network
/etc/network/if-up.d
/etc/network/if-up.d/postfix
/etc/network/if-down.d
/etc/network/if-down.d/postfix
/etc/postfix
/etc/postfix/postfix-script
/etc/postfix/post-install
/etc/postfix/postfix-files
/etc/resolvconf
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d
/etc/resolvconf/update-libc.d/postfix
/var/spool/postfix
/var/spool/postfix/usr
/var/spool/postfix/usr/lib
/var/spool/postfix/usr/lib/zoneinfo
/var/lib/postfix
root@randevu:~#
```

This is what is left from postfix. Maybe it's some kind of crash on whole **partition**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check /var/log/dpkg.log what had happend with postfix.

And than just make backups on your existing files and then reinstall the package.